# Will updating contact billing info in CiviCRM automatically update in Authorize.net?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, payment, authorize.net

My client is seeing a few failed recurring contribution transactions per week. I believe these are due to expired Credit Card details (expiration date). I'm wondering if I should enable this setting in Authorize, but I haven't confirmed that Authorize's billing info gets automatically updated when a contact's credit card info is updated in Civi.

[image]